React Dialog Modal Is Appearing before User Clicks the intended button
I have a todo app which I am working on, the intended flow is for the user to input their "Todo" and click create which adds the todo to a list of Todos, with each todo then getting an edit button. The modal is meant to appear on clicking the edit button which would allows the user to describe their todo in detail. However at the moment the Modal is popping up when the user creates the Todo.
THE TODOLIST COMPONENT
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function TodoList( {todos, setTodos} ) {
    const [editingItemId, setEditingItemId] = useState(null)

    function editTask(id) {
        setTodos(todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? (
            {...todo, isEditing: !todo.isEditing}
        ) : todo
        ));
        setEditingItemId(id)
    }

    

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
            {todos.map((todo, index) => (
                <TodoItem 
                key={index} 
                task={todo}
                editTask={editTask}
                editingItemId={editingItemId}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

THE TODOITEM COMPONENT
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function TodoItem({ task, editTask, editingItemId }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (task.isEditing && task.id === editingItemId) {
            displayDialog();
        }
    }, [task.isEditing, task.id, editingItemId]);

    function displayDialog() {
        document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-span-4">
                <h2>{task.task}</h2>
                {task.description ? <p>{task.description}</p> : (
                    <button
                        onClick={() => editTask(task.id)}
                        className="bg-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-900 text-white font-bold px-2 py-1 m-1 rounded-2xl">
                        Describe your task
                    </button>
                )}
            </div>
            <dialog className="flex flex-col p-12 rounded-lg bg-slate-900 text-white">
                <h2 className="uppercase">{task.task}</h2>
                <textarea cols="60" rows="14" className="bg-slate-900 border border-white" />
            </dialog>
        </>
    );
}



You are trying to mix vanilla javascript DOM manipulation with React. You will likely want to pick one or the other, otherwise React's internal React component tree will get out of sync with the DOM and you will get a million bugs. To do this the React way, you would typically render the dialog conditionally, rather than trying to show/hide it using CSS. Something like...
return (
    <>
        <div className="col-span-4">
            <h2>{task.task}</h2>
            {task.description ? <p>{task.description}</p> : (
                <button
                    onClick={() => editTask(task.id)}
                    className="bg-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-900 text-white font-bold px-2 py-1 m-1 rounded-2xl">
                    Describe your task
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
        { editingItemId === task.id &&
          <dialog className="flex flex-col p-12 rounded-lg bg-slate-900 text-white">
              <h2 className="uppercase">{task.task}</h2>
              <textarea cols="60" rows="14" className="bg-slate-900 border border-white" />
          </dialog>
        }
    </>
);


Yes I had resolved this in pretty much this exact way thanks for the answer. I had a gut feeling that JS dom manipulation was the wrong choice and this clarified it for me :)
